# Should i use custom post type for a custom footer?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, images, footer

I am trying to develop a customized footer so that depending on what page the user is on, the site will display a different footer.

Basically the footer will remain pretty much the same except it will display three different images of three destinations that are relevant to the page its on. These images will also link to an external sister site.

This is easy enough to do with a bunch of php files include in some ifelse statements. And that was the way i was going to take this idea, but then i thought that it would be much better if i create an interface in WP admin so that if anyone wants to change a destination and/or image they could easily do it from the admin panel, thus allowing anyone the ability to do so without the need for accessing code.

So the question is shall I create custom post types or is there another way to do this? Ideally I would like an admin menu like 'footer' then have sub-menu's for each region/destination and each sub-menu will have three posts/sections that will contain an image a title and a url to place in the link.

Any help and pointers will be much appreciated :)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`dynamic_sidebar()`](http://queryposts.com/?s=dynamic_sidebar)s for that. [You can read more about it in Code](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar).

They allow you to use widgets, like - for example - a custom menu widget. More about the custom menus inside [wp-nav-menu](/questions/tagged/wp-nav-menu).

Comment: Hi @Kaiser, Thanks for your reply. I hadn't thought of using custom sidebar for this. Sounds like a good idea, i will look into it further. Many thanks :)